# how to make a like search in postgresql and node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sql-like

I am using node js and the module pg for connect to postrgresql
i want to make a search for a database of tags but i can't make it work,
in the variable tag i saved the param of  the url , but the consult doesn't return any results.
how can i fix?

```
app.get("/tags", function(req, res){
        var tag = req.query.q;
        res.json(tag)
        var search = db.client.query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name LIKE '%$1%'", [tag], function(err, result){
                res.json(result);
            }
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 54):

I don't know the node.js PostgreSQL interface that well but I think I can see the problem. This is an SQL string literal that contains a numbered placeholder:

```
'%$1%'
```

The `$1` inside that string won't be replaced with the value of `tag` because placeholders inside strings are not placeholders at all, they're just substrings that happen to have the same form as a placeholder.

The two usual options are:

1. Add the `%` wildcards in the client code.
2. Concatenate the `%` wildcards onto the strings inside the database.

The first one would look like this:

```
db.client.query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name LIKE $1", ['%' + tag + '%'], ...
```

and the second like this:

```
db.client.query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name LIKE '%' || $1 || '%'", [tag], ...
```

Use whichever approach you prefer.

Comment: I guess the first version allows less sql injections than the second. The second one seems more vulnerable.

Comment: @Heribert Not really, `$1` will be properly escaped for SQL before the SQL string concatenation happens so it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: You can use first one with ```[`%${tag}%`]```  must be ` not '.   And ILIKE instead of LIKE to avoid case sensitive

Answer (score 19):

an ES6 solution would be something like:

```
client.query('select * from users where user_name Ilike $1', [`%${req.query.q}%`], (err1, result) => { ...
```

Comment: This was down voted and its not clear why, does anyone see a security concern here?

Comment: @James I don't see any downvotes on this answer so maybe they changed their mind, perhaps someone was confusing the `$1` placeholder in single quotes with string interpolation and then realized their mistake. Anyway, looks like an ES6 adaptation of my string concatenation (but with the case-insensitive ILIKE instead of LIKE), I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: What's slightly "wrong" perhaps is that the % syntax is moved from the query pattern to the parameter. The second option in @mu-is-too-short's answer seems a better choice.